# How to check django model data type?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a django model consist of 140 columns which contain 10 date types, 60 char types, 70 number types.

```
class SOA_detail(models.Model):
    ...
```

Is there a way to group up by data types and place the column name in a `list`.

```
char_fields = [] # storage for character fields column name
num_fields  = [] # storage for number fields column name
date_fields = [] # storage for date fields column name
```

So far I know is to take the column name.

```
 # take all field names from model
 for model_field in SOA_detail._meta._fields():
      if #datatype is char: ---??
          char_fields.append(model_field.name)
      elif #datatype is num: ---??
          num_fields.append(model_field.name)
      elif #datatype is date: ---??
          date_field.append(model_field.name)
```

Thank you for your time reading my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a builtin method in python called isinstance which checks if an object is an instance of a specific class or not, using this method you can do it like this:

```
for model_field in SOA_detail._meta._fields():
  if isinstance(model_field, CharField):
      char_fields.append(model_field.name)
  elif isinstance(model_field, IntegerField):
      num_fields.append(model_field.name)
  elif isinstance(model_filed, DateTimeField):
      date_field.append(model_field.name)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`isinstance`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance).

For example:

```
>>> from django.db import models
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> [f.name for f in User._meta.fields if isinstance(f, models.CharField)]
['password', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
>>> [f.name for f in User._meta.fields if isinstance(f, models.DateTimeField)]
['last_login', 'date_joined']
>>> [f.name for f in User._meta.fields if isinstance(f, models.IntegerField)]
[]
>>> [f.name for f in User._meta.fields if isinstance(f, models.AutoField)]
[u'id']
```

Comment: this is a great example, sir.